# Cannot override Windows 7 Autologon

Tags: windows-7, autologon

I am using Windows 7

I have configured my registry to Autologon with Username1 / Password1.

Normal / Desired procedure:

```
Computer starts
I interrupt the Autologon by pressing the Shift Key
The "Press Alt+Ctrl+Del" screen appears
I press Alt+Ctrl+Del
I see the messagebox where I enter the Username and Password
I enter my Username2 and Password2
I login as Username2
```

This is my computer's procedure:

```
Computer starts
I interrupt the Autologon by pressing the Shift Key
The "Press Alt+Ctrl+Del" screen appears
I press Alt+Ctrl+Del
The computer logs in with the registry credentials (Username1 + Password1).
```

**iff** these credentials are wrong, then the message "wrong username/password" will be displayed and I will be prompted to enter Username+Password.

Has anyone else ever faced this problem?
What could cause this problem? some registry settings? some policies? something else?

Comment: Just disable the default username.  If you made any register modifications that is the reason its not working as it should.

Comment: I need this to login with the default username and password. But I also need to interrupt it at will.

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis: I would suggest you try to set up your autologon with the tool from Sysinternals. Maybe you got some setting wrong in the registry (compare what the tool puts in). On top it allows you to encrypt the password, so it does not show up in the registry in plain text. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx

Comment: @TheUser1024 Thanks for the suggestion. I do have made the same configurations in many other computers. All through registry. I compared the registry settings (even all policies I could find) with other computers that have the desired procedure. Everything seems to be the same. (unless there other registry folders responsible for this, apart from the /winlogon)

Comment: @TheUser1024 I also have used the Autologon tool. But same result. After Shift and Alt+Ctrl+Del i am not being prompted for credentials.